# Find postcodes within 16km Range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, geo, geography

i have a table (`[dbo].[LUPostCode]`) with postcode, Lattitude and longitude. (27K records).
I have another table (`[dbo].[LUPostCodeMaster]`) , a master table with  same structure, have (2.5 Million records).

I need to find out all the postcodes from `[dbo].[LUPostCodeMaster]` which is **16Km (or) less** distant from Postcodes in `[dbo].[LUPostCode]`

I am trying

```
SELECT  C.skMasterPostCode PostCode,
        M.skMasterPostCode AdjPostCode
INTO    WorkTable
FROM    [dbo].[LUPostCode] C,
        (
        SELECT [skMasterPostCode],[Latitude],[Longitude] 
        FROM    [dbo].[LUPostCodeMaster]
        ) M --Expected rows --> 70,771,012,410
WHERE   CAST('POINT('+C.Latitude+ ' '+C.Longitude+')' AS GEOGRAPHY).STDistance(CAST('POINT('+M.Latitude+ ' '+M.Longitude+')' AS GEOGRAPHY)) <= 16000
```

It is taking so much time..I know it is a bad idea to `CROSS JOIN` `27K with 2.5 Million`.

Can anyone suggest a better Idea.

Comment: Where's 16km come from? Is that going to change on each request? The only obvious way I see is to calculate all these in a join table but that'll require a lot of storage!

Comment: I think it must be just fine, for the time being I use a set of generated data..

Comment: @Liath - you can download the postcode/location data from the [Ordnance Survey](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) "Code-Point Open provides a precise geographic location for each postcode unit in Great Britain"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sweet - they must have changed the rules since I was looking at it!

Answer (score 2):

```
-- DROP TABLE #mytemptable 

SELECT 
 C.UID  AS uidC
,M.UID AS uidM
,CAST('POINT(' + C.Latitude + ' ' + C.Longitude + ')' AS GEOGRAPHY)
.STDistance(CAST('POINT(' + M.Latitude+ ' ' + M.Longitude+')' AS GEOGRAPHY))
 AS distance 
INTO #mytemptable 
FROM LUPostCode AS C
CROSS JOIN LUPostCodeMaster AS M 


DELETE FROM #mytemptable WHERE distance > 16000    


SELECT * FROM #mytemptable 

LEFT JOIN LUPostCode AS C
    ON C.uid = uidC
LEFT JOIN LUPostCodeMaster AS M 
    ON M.uid = uidM
```

Works within 15 seconds on my 4 million entry sample table.

Well, according to 
http://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/07/22/clr-vs-t-sql-performance-considerations/
you can still move it to a CLR function.
That might cut the time in half.

[image: CLR Speed]

And well, you're still doing a computation on 67.5 billion combinations, so it simply takes some time.

Comment: Looks like the temp table #mytemptable will have an estimated 70,771,012,410 records. Will that an issue?

Comment: I tried your Query. The Insertion into #table took 1 hour 30 Mins, It was still running, so I stopped.
May be it takes time for larger data. As I mentioned earlier, it is 27K with 2.5 Million.

Comment: @Jithin Shaji: Well, doing a computation on 67.5 billion combinations just takes some time. You might be able to cut the time in half by using a CLR function instead of stDistance, but that's about it. What are you trying to achive anyway ?

Comment: there is an upcoming project, I need to do some preparations by creating some lookUp tables.
I need a Cross reference table with every post code in UK and all postcodes with in 16 km range (for each post code)